# iOS10 UITextView touch event crash

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer, ios10, uitapgesturerecognizer

**I have a very strange issue, UITextView touch event crash on double tap whereas same code works with < iOS10 version. (It means below iOS10 version there is no crash for press gesture recognizer)**

Actually, I am adding the **double tap** and **log press** gesture based on permission. If the user has permission to comment then add gestures in **viewDidLoad** methods. **Comment is allowed only with double tap or long press**

```
singleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapGestureAction:)];
singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

// adding gesture to open window for commenting only when he has writing access

if (canComment) {

    longPressgesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressGestureAction:)];
    longPressgesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
    doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

}
```

**On single tap**

```
-(void)singleTapGestureAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer{

if (isSingleTapped) {
    isSingleTapped = NO;
    return;
}

isSingleTapped = YES;

UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)tapGestureRecognizer.view;

[self.commentView becomeFirstResponder]; // becomeFirstResponder
}
```

**On double tap**

```
-(void)doDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tapGestureRecognizer
{
     UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)tapGestureRecognizer.view;
     [self.commentView becomeFirstResponder]; // becomeFirstResponder

     // To show the UIMenuController menu
     [self setCommentMenuToolTipWithRect:completeRect];
}
```

NOTE: I am adding [self.commentView becomeFirstResponder]; on every gesture action

**UITextView delegate methods**

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)inView
{

    [self.commentView becomeFirstResponder];
    range=[self.commentView selectedRange];    
}
```

**USE CASE:**

When I double tap to select any word then <del>**APP CRASH**</del> and UIMenuController does not appear, [image]

but if I add the following line **app does not crash**

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
}  // app does not crash
```

and UIMenuController appears with comment menu items that's great. I was happy that I have fixed the crash issue.

> **But there is another problem, when I press outside, menu hides and
>   select any word AGAIN then It does not appear SECOND time.**

---

> **I have tried all the possible way to show the menu for returns
>   YES/TRUE to canBecomeFirstResponder. I know, there has to be a view
>   that claims firstResponder for the menu to show. but how ?**

On second time touch, not even calling any gesture recognizer method

Comment: All details below the **USE CASE:** header are confusing. Is your problem the crash or tool tip? Please update your question accordingly and remove all irrelevant information.

Comment: @lukya. First of all its crashing double tap on UITextView, but then if I add textViewDidChangeSelection then it does not crash but then tooltip does not appear

Comment: Thats impossible to solve just looking at your question. If possible, provide the source code (via github etc).

Comment: @lukya ok. I will

Comment: You should add swift tag instead of iPad or iPhone.

Comment: @Ramis no, it's objective-c samples, so it's not a Swift specific question.

Comment: @lukya https://github.com/pvn/PKDemo.git

Answer (score 2):

From the logs it is clear that when double tap is recognized, same touch update is also sent to another gesture recognizer, which fails.
So, a simple solution would be to avoid detection of other gestures on double tap.
This can simply be achieved by making all other gestures on `commentView` require `doubleTap` to fail using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail`. just add the condition in `addGestureToTextView` method as shown below.

```
if (withDoubleTap && self.canScreenPlayEdit) {
    [self.commentView removeGestureRecognizer:singleTapGesture];
    [self.commentView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [self.commentView addGestureRecognizer:longPressgesture];

    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.commentView.gestureRecognizers) {
        [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
    }
}
```

This does solve the crash and also shows the menu without calling `resignFirstResponder` in `textViewDidChangeSelection`.

However, there seem to be many issues in your code. `PLSceneDetailsVC` is too complicated and you need to simplify the code. You need to streamline the gesture management or you will end up facing many more such issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I followed the same as you suggested, the crash is not happening but menu does not show second time. It show when you long press but I want to show the menu when user double tap on any text.

Comment: Well, you have too many gestures added in too many places.  My code suggestion only solves the crash you mentioned and open the context menu the first time. For further issues you need to cleanup your code a lot.

Comment: thanks. But my question still remain same. As I mentioned in my query "But there is another problem, when I press outside, menu hides and select any word AGAIN then It does not appear SECOND time."

Comment: Your code is too messy to debug to find the exact problem you mention in above. You have too many visual elements without any legible layout and too many gestures which are added/removed too many times. If you clean up your code significantly, and upload it again, i could take look the code again.

Comment: The other option for you is **trial and error** method. Comment out parts of your code and see of the problem still exists. If yes the code you commented is not a suspect. Uncomment everything and start over with other sections of the code. e.g. 1. comment out ALL gesture related code except double tap 2. comment out all other interactive UI elements on the screen 3. Implement a single text view on a simple view controller with only the double tap etc. This sound very stupid and un-scientific but if you do not refactor your code into modular pieces, this remains the only way to debug it.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, let me refactor the code again and check once again from my end, then will get back to you with positive hope so.

Comment: One simple change to improve your code is to set up **all** the gestures you need in view did load. It means create, add to respective views, set dependencies as shown in my answer etc. and then wherever required, you can simply `enable` or `disable` the gestures instead of adding and removing them through out the code..

Answer (score 1):

```
 longPressgesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.2;
```

My guess the problem is here. 0.2s is way too small to be used for longPress. Probably both were triggered (longPress and double tap).

Change it to higher like 1.5s.